# View module diplaying wrong content type extra

Tags: views, nodes

I am having a problem with the views module in Drupal. Everytime I add a new content type, views will display an other content type. I have tried different things, but I can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the link:
http://carlosgandara.com

[image: Screenshot of content types administration page]
Here is my view settings...
Quotes is the only content type that I want to display.

[image: Screenshot of view settings page]

[image: Screenshot of view block output]

Here is the quote block, but every time I add an other content type. For some reason, it replaces the content with the other content type.

[image: Screenshot of the view block output after adding a new content type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a filter - filter by content and choose the content type you want to show or use a contextual filter(advanced settings) to show only the content type you want to show. Right now youre not filtering so your view is set to show all content types.

In the example below I have a relationship of author. I have a contextual filter set up with this relationship so that it will only show content with this relationship and finally i have a filter that only shows content types of the kind flashcard and only the content where the logged in user is the author of the content.

[image]

There is a great set of tutorials about views [here](http://nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) at nodeone